# Getting rid of cookie value with double quotes

Tags: php, python, django, cookies, setcookie

I am currently doing a Restful API using Python/Django with django-rest-framework package. I tried to do a call from a PHP client in which cookie must be set for authentication purpose.

In my django end, this is what was done:

```
def SetToken(request):
    """
    Set token string to cookie
    """

    if 'token' in request.GET:
        token_str = request.GET['token']
        response = HttpResponse()
        response.set_cookie("ttsessid", token_str)
        return response
```

Thus, the cookie, "ttsessid" was created. However, I realized that long token value will result in quoted cookie value being created. These are some example scenario:

Example 1: Short string, no quotes:

```
token = 2xYlyVhBKRgtAY2dzFMWDwoedV569keWKJfpNZCqLdMaQe5x38Bi9j5Pept3E%2BBdSSRyfq9zgR8KYnAqG4p%2Pept3E%2BBdSSRyfq9zgR8KYnAqG4p%2

"ttsessid" value = 2xYlyVhBKRgtAY2dzFMWDwoedV569keWKJfpNZCqLdMaQe5x38Bi9j5Pept3E%2BBdSSRyfq9zgR8KYnAqG4p%2Pept3E%2BBdSSRyfq9zgR8KYnAqG4p%2
```

Example 2: Longer string, double quotes resulted:

```
token = 2xYlyVhBKRgtAY2dzFMWDwoedV569keWKJfpNZCqLdMaQe5x38Bi9j5Pept3E%2BBdSSRyfq9zgR8KYnAqG4p%2Pept3E%2BBdSSRyfq9zgR8KYnAqG4p%2BoHOs2AvfQ2pPP7eiLaxBCkRaCC4SUZ8zvC%2F9DwbcTXSMnj5H0qJVt1XjnIPVLJ6GcWd6t9

"ttsessid" value = "2xYlyVhBKRgtAY2dzFMWDwoedV569keWKJfpNZCqLdMaQe5x38Bi9j5Pept3E%2BBdSSRyfq9zgR8KYnAqG4p%2Pept3E%2BBdSSRyfq9zgR8KYnAqG4p%2BoHOs2AvfQ2pPP7eiLaxBCkRaCC4SUZ8zvC%2F9DwbcTXSMnj5H0qJVt1XjnIPVLJ6GcWd6t9"(Notice the double quotes)
```

I have checked the string. It does not contain any prohibited characters such as '=' or '&', so I'm not sure what was wrong with it.

I hope someone can help me out on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is. Are you referring to the “%” codes in your tokens? which would be due to this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp#encodingresult